# Gradle subproject cannot access own resources

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multiproject Gradle build, with a setup similar to:

```
A
-- src
   -- main
      -- java
         -- A.java
B
-- src
   -- main
      -- java
         -- B.java
      -- resources
         -- B.resource
```

A depends on B, and B has a dependency on its own resource B.resource. The application is built with `gradle distZip`. During runtime, B cannot access its own resource as it is zipped inside a .jar file.

The command B is using to access its resource is:

```
String res = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
        getResource("B.resource").getFile();
```

I understand that the Spring web framework offers a ClassResourceLoader or similar, but I don't have access to this. Is there any that B can access B.resource when A is the application and B its dependency?

Comment: Perhaps the context classloader is not the classloader which loads your classes? Try `A.class.getClassloader().getResource("B.resource")`

Comment: I tried this (using B.class rather than A.class - B cannot see A) and had the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the Gradle forums. Instead of attempting to obtain the resource as a file, obtain it as a stream and read it out from the stream.

```
B.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("B.resource");
```